# firebase.firestore() is not a function, I tried all solutions but not resolved

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm sure many of you are tired of seeing this question. Although I looked at almost all of the answers to these questions and tried it, I haven't solved it.

First, when I tried

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'

firebase: "6.0.2"
firebase/firestore: 6.0.2
```

I got

```
 __firebase.default.firestore is not a function. (In '_firebase.default.firestore()', '_firebase.default.firestore' is undefined)
```

also

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

then I got the same.

next

```
import { firebase } from '@firebase/app';
import '@firebase/firestore';

"@firebase/app": "0.6.4",
"@firebase/firestore": "1.14.6",
```

I didn't get any error but I couldn't fetch the data.

I think I did other things but I don't remember.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: "I didn't get any error but I couldn't fetch the data." => can you show the code you used ?

Comment: fireStore
        .collection('users')
        .doc('KgZLhZvgTiTSYJ7VBFbfutjjtUE2')
        .get()
        .then((doc) => {
          if (doc.exists) {
            console.log(doc.data());
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))

Comment: Did you see any error while fetching data. IF not, then may doc.exists doesn't return true and you doc does't exist on firestore

Comment: well, yes it does, because it returns the data when I implemented the code on expo snack's web player. It doesn't work only on Android and iOS.

Comment: you said you used "fireStore", maybe the uppercase "S" is the issue.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain aabout it. const fireStore = firebase.firestore()

Comment: The fact you had troubles fetching data from Firestore doesn't mean that your import are wrong. Could you edit your question with how are you exporting the data and what responses are you getting?